# Embed Windows.winmd into c# project and load as embedded resource?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, embedding, winmd

I want to use the Windows Action Center Notifications in my desktop application without making it a Windows Store App, which I have successfully done, with my application, all DLLs are embedded as resources and not exposed outside the exe. I also obfuscate the code to make it so programs like jet brains dot peek cannot decompile for source code. The issue is that loading a dll works fine, but it fails with the message "Unsupported type" when the program launches. This is due to the obfuscation and encryption. Even if I run the exe through my obfuscator with all protections disabled, it still fails to run. So my question is, how do I load the Windows.winmd file as a DLL that is included in the project as an embedded resource(and changing the extension to a DLL does NOT work as it returns a different error with an HRESULT code)?
Is it possible to do with DLLImport? Should I just write a different DLL as an access layer to the Windows.winmd classes?
Reference for original embedding source project: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/528178/Load-DLL-From-Embedded-Resource

Comment: That doesn't make any sense and cannot solve your problem, a .winmd file is only used for building a program.   Use a telephone instead, call the obfuscator vendor for support.

Comment: The obfuscator is open source and a .winmd file is a metadata file for Windows APIs which is used by Store Apps.